# IPC using signaling

Tags: c, linux, fork

Given a parent process `P1` and two children processes `P2` and `P3`, I would like after that `P2` terminates to send a signal from `P2` to `P3` (in stand-by) so he could start. I do not want to use `waitpid()` from the partent `P1`, instead I want the signaling mechanism engage both `P2` and `P3` while `P1` is just monitoring the events. I have actually had a look at the `kill()` command, but I could not however know which type of signal should I use in this scenario. Any idea please?

Comment: This is a very open-ended question, because there are a number of valid IPC mechanisms that could suit your needs.  You can indeed use `kill` with whatever signal you want (except the unblockable ones), but for your use I would suggest either `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2` to avoid overloading the meaning of the other standard signals.

Comment: If P2 is sending the signal it cannot happen after P2 terminates.  P2 will have to send the signal before it terminates.

Comment: @WilliamPursell ... although it could possibly send the signal from an exit handler or other function that is arranged to be called only after the main part of the program has finished. Even something like a C++ singleton destructor... A lot more information needed before a "best" approach can even be imagined...